# MySQL Insert: Avoid duplicates w/ multiple cols

Tags: php, mysql

I basically want to insert two Values ('Val', 1) into the columns (`cls`, `jg`) of the table t1.
Although `cls` is set to be unique, jg has to appear multiple times with the same value, so INSERT IGNORE wouldn't work. Thorefore, I have to check if the pair ('Val', 1) already exists, and if not so, I have to insert these values.

I tried it this way:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (`cls`,`jg`)
SELECT 'Val',1 FROM cls WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM cls WHERE `cls`='Val' AND `jg`=1)
LIMIT 1;
```

But it doesn't work when the table is empty, because then the outer select statement doesn't contain any entries…

How should I proceed? I have no idea how to handle this a different way…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an unique composite index on cls, jg.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE t1 ADD UNIQUE  INDEX(cls(200), jg)
```

Then use

```
INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Comment: That gives me `BLOB/TEXT column 'cls' used in key specification without a key length`; probably because cls is already unique itself?

Comment: Im not sure,try dropping the constraint on cls.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken. If you have a unique constraint (like a primary key) on `cls` that doesn't in any way interfere with the values of `jg`.

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f13533/1)

Comment: But I don't want to check if the value of `cls` already exists, I want to check on both `cls` _and_ `jg`. E.g. if I Had an entry ('XYZ', 1) in the table, it would be correct to insert ('Value', 1) — but when there already is ('Value', 1) inside, it wouldn't.

Comment: Oh, I mis-read the question then. @Mihai is correct, do a composite index on both fields and then a normal INSERT IGNORE.